# How do I enable http compression in tomcat for static files inside the war file?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6, http-compression

I want to enable tomcat to deliver files stored in the WAR file using http-compression.

This question if specific to tomcat, please do not suggest using another webserver.

It would be great if this could be achieved only from the tomcat configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [GZIP compression](http://www.servletworld.com/tomcat/enable-tomcat-gzip-compression.html) which you can configure in your Tomcat connector.